# Wrapper around TASKs in C#

Tags: unit-testing, asynchronous, c#-4.0, task-parallel-library, task

I am using tasks in WinForms (`.NET 4.0`) to perform lengthy operations like `WCF` call. Application is already in product with heavy use of Tasks (almost all the methods which uses Tasks are `void`).

During the unit testing we have used `AutoResetEvent`s (in actual code) to find out when the given task is completed then perform assert.

This gives me a thought that almost all the `AutoResetEvent` are waste of effort. They are just fulfilling unit testing needs, nothing else.

Can we create a wrapper around Tasks likewise when actual code run... they should work in background and in case of unit testing they should be synchronous.

Similar to below link for `BackgroundWorker`.

http://si-w.co.uk/blog/2009/09/11/unit-testing-code-that-uses-a-backgroundworker/

Comment: Why can't you use `Wait()` on those tasks to find when they complete?

Comment: Methods are already written long back with void. Updating all the methods with Task return will be very big task.

Comment: I thought you already want to update the methods to remove `AutoResetEvent`s and introduce the `Task` wrapper. How is what I suggested any worse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you simply use the continuation for tasks in your wrapper, like this:

```
var task = ...
task.ContinueWith(t => check task results here)
```

Also, [unit tests can be marked as `async`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn818494.aspx), if they have a return type `Task`, so you can use an `await` there, and after that do your asserts:

```
[Test]
public async Task SynchronizeTestWithRecurringOperationViaAwait()
{
    var sut = new SystemUnderTest();
    // Execute code to set up timer with 1 sec delay and interval.
    var firstNotification = sut.StartRecurring();
    // Wait that operation has finished two times.
    var secondNotification = await firstNotification.GetNext();
    await secondNotification.GetNext();
    // Assert outcome.
    Assert.AreEqual("Init Poll Poll", sut.Message);
}
```

Another approach (from the same article) is to use a custom task scheduler, which will be synchronous in case of unit testing:

```
[Test]
public void TestCodeSynchronously()
{
    var dts = new DeterministicTaskScheduler();
    var sut = new SystemUnderTest(dts);
    // Execute code to schedule first operation and return immediately.
    sut.StartAsynchronousOperation();
    // Execute all operations on the current thread.
    dts.RunTasksUntilIdle();
    // Assert outcome of the two operations.
    Assert.AreEqual("Init Work1 Work2", sut.Message);
}
```

Same MSDN magazine contains nice [article about best practices for `async` unit testing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn818493.aspx). Also `async void` should be used only as an event handler, all other methods should have `async Task` signature.

Comment: like I mentioned in my question... I am using .NET 4.0 so cannot use async and await

Comment: @Abhash786 You can, using `Microsoft.Bcl.Async`. Though it does require C# 5.0 compiler.